# Root certificates are missing for certificate validation. Either pass them in using the ca_certs parameter or install certifi to use it automatically

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am using `django-elasticsearch-dsl` in one of our projects, and after creating a cluster in AWS Elasticsearch, I started seeing this error: `Root certificates are missing for certificate validation. Either pass them in using the ca_certs parameter or install certifi to use it automatically.`. There are some solutions proposed to solve the issue for `https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io` in this linke [link][1], but that is not for `django-elasticsearch-dsl` which is using `elasticsearch-py`. I only can set the endpoint through the `settings.py` like this:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'https://my-aws-elasticsearch-endpoint.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com'
    }
}
```

How can I add/enable this certificate for `django-elasticsearch-dsl`

Answer (score 9):

`pip install certifi` should do the trick, as the message suggests. `elasticsearch-py` will automatically look it up.